# Какие значения может принимать поле detailed_status в pyowm?

Tags: python, pyowm

```
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
weather = observation.weather
status = weather.detailed_status
```

меня интересуют все возможные значения этого поля, в доках я этого не нашёл

Comment: А в исходника случайно не заглядывали?

Comment: заглядывал, но что-то не совсем разобрался, мне гораздо удобнее читать код, написанный на яп со статической типизацией

Comment: ладно, я пожалуй данные о погоде буду брать из другого источника, так как pyowm выдаёт какие-то недостоверные данные